# Clang Pragma Comprehensive List

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm

Where can I find the documentation of **all** possible `#pragma`s available in Xcode's Clang/LLVM?

I found [this in the Clang user manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas), and even tried grepping through the [svn repo](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk), but still could not find documentation for things like `_Pragma("clang assume_nonnull begin")`.

Any hints where to look?

Comment: Looking for Clang, not GCC. Also could not find assume_nonnull there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing everything right, the only thing you're missing is: Clang we have in Xcode is different from Clang we can download at http://clang.llvm.org.

You can obtain Apple's version of compiler at http://opensource.apple.com under 'Developer tools', but usually there is pretty old version.

Whenever Apple engineers introduce something new into the compiler it's usually not available publicly yet, but they push these features into the public repo during following months.

Previously it happened with arm64, and now with nullability qualifiers.

Check the public repo again, they started pushing nullability qualifiers couple of days ago, also feel free to subscribe to [Clang Developers Mailing List](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) for updates.

Comment: Awesome! As far as I can tell, only Xcode 6.2 developer tools have been pushed to Apple's open source page, too bad this is lagging behind.

Comment: probably because transparent boxes cannot be shiny on the outside.

Comment: Since Swift became opensource, Apples fork of clang is also on github: https://github.com/apple/swift-clang/blob/stable/lib/Lex/Pragma.cpp